# Patch Java class import to use a different class instead

Tags: java, maven, classloader, javac

We have a third party library that transitively pulls in `backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent`. We can use Maven to ban that, but the third party library code imports classes from the `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent` package.

Does Java or Maven provide a way to force any `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util...` import to instead use `java.util...`? Preferably that substitution could be forced at both compile time and runtime, so that we can be sure the API is being implemented fully enough to be dropped in without obvious breakage.

Comment: Maybe it would help to take a look at maven-shade-plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html ?

Comment: No direct use of Java/Maven but related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39742821/3080094

Comment: Thank you! The `maven-shade-plugin` looks like a good lead, but we're not building shaded JARs right now. In this specific example, we're packaging up the libraries as a WAR. We may ultimately move to shaded JARs in the future. Until then, is there a way to take advantage of the ability to rewrite a library JAR's bytecode while still building WARs?